# How can I run fullCalendar in internet explorer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, fullcalendar

I don't have any problem to run it in chrome/firefox but in internet explorer it not appears:
Is there any solution?

html:

```
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({


        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        }, .....
```

Answer (score 1):

## Updated

This works also in IE:

http://jsfiddle.net/j6r4D/

I think you are messing up some of your `{` `}` somewhere...

## **OLD:**

Are you using `IE9`?

> http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/support/

Fullcalendar has not been tested with Internet Explorer 9 so it might not work...

**EDIT:**

Just tested the demopage in IE9 and it works. So this is not the problem.

Comment: okThanks for your answer.I can´t view that page so I think it can be ActiveX configuration. I will try it at home becouse in my work I can´t change those configurations

Comment: Why would active X matter? I think you need to provide a link here, because the answer is most likely how you are getting the information with which you populate the calendar. IE sucks at ajax even more than it sucks at everything else.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely a comma at the end of a property or callback that should not be there. Make sure that all callbacks are deliminated by a comma except for the last one. Do the same with all of your properties within the callbacks. Typically this is it. If it doesn't change anything, please post the entire code for the calendar so that we can look at it in it's entirety. I am currently using fullcalendar and it is functional in all browsers including ie6, ie7, ie8, and ie9 right out of the box.